# dpkg error when trying to install ssh server

Tags: upgrade, ssh, dpkg

```
Linux klu 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I want to install ssh server for my laptop. I tried many ways but it did't work
so please give me the correct procedure to install the ssh server.
when i use the `sudo apt-get upgrade`or `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` I get

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
files list for package 'distro-info-data' is not a regular file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to fix problems with apt?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of command `ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info/distro-info-data.list`

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install openssh-client

sudo apt-get install openssh-server

As far as I know the client allows you to access other machines, while the server allows other machines to access yours.

Comment: This is correct, but may not work if dpkg and apt are having trouble. The root problem seems to be a dpkg issue.